# Stata batch called from Python: Pipe Stata console output to command line

Tags: python, python-3.x, batch-file, stata

I have a Python script, which calls several Stata `do` files:

```
from subprocess import call
Stata_exec = "D:/Stata 12 MP2/StataMP-64.exe"
dofile = "D:/Test.do" 
call( "\"{0}\" do /e \"{1}\"".format(Stata_exec, dofile), shell=True)
```

Here is a test `do` file:

```
/* Merge some big files */

clear *

// Create dataset A (8000 variables, 300 observations)
set obs 300
gen ID = _n
forval i = 1/8000 {
    gen variableA`i' = runiform()
}
tempfile dataA
save "`dataA'"

// Create dataset B (5000 variables, 300 observations)
clear 
set obs 300
gen ID = _n
forval i = 1/5000 {
    gen variableB`i' = runiform()
}

sort ID

// Attempt merge
merge 1:1 ID using `dataA'
exit, clear
```

I would like to have the progress of the `do` file piped to the console in real time, so it will be integrated with the other Python output.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `log` command to echo copy of a Stata session to a file, or maybe the `file` command to write specific messages (like "Data A Created") to a text file. Python should be able to display such files with `subprocess.call(["tail", "-F", logfilename])`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had thought about logging and then opening the log in the console after the do file is complete. The problem is that the .do files I am batch submitting take a long time to complete, during which the only console output is a python print statement `print("Do file running...")`. My main desire is to have visual evidence in the console that Stata is doing something in the background.

Comment: You can periodically "peek" at the log while Stata is working. No need to wait until the end.

Comment: this might need to be a separate question, but how would I go about peeking at a stata log file (in python script) that is being written during the execution of a python command in that same script.

Comment: I have windows, and it's saying tail is not a recognized command (I am unfortunately not working with the ease of Unix). Also, am I wrong in assuming that `subprocess.call(["tail", "-F", logfilename])` would not fire until after the above `call( "\"{0}\" do /e \"{1}\"".format(Stata_exec, dofile), shell=True)` is complete, thus missing the point? I am new to `subprocess` though and could be totally wrong.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov if you find some free time can you please expand your answer a bit? Thanks.

Comment: @PearlySpencer Might take me some time, but I will try.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov a gentle reminder to please expand your answer.